# Particle physics and quantum numbers

Tags: particle-physics

Elementary particles contain many quantum numbers which are usually said to be intrinsic to them. If we see a particle that has a same mass, charge and spin of an electron could not be an electron if the particle has not the others quantum numbers.

Where can I find the exact quantum numbers that define a particle?

In experiment, like in partcile accelerator, are checked all quantum numbers of a particle to be sure that is a known particle?

Comment: Particle physics texts and the PDG cover all these amply.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you, about second question what you can tell me?

Comment: Of course, all quantum numbers are checked for consistency, when possible.

Comment: You *have* explored [this site](http://pdg.lbl.gov), haven't you?

Comment: There's a lot of information, it takes much time and I'm new in partcle physics. Thank you for the site.